# Menu is jumping around from foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the site the menu is jumping around (the drop down)
You can see it here : http://hoerecenterlimfjord.dk/

How do i fix this? I think its because it is done by JavaScript, but how do I remove this jumping effect? I need to use foundation because else i need to change the whole website. So if anyone got any idea to how i change this "jumping" effect so it wont jumping around when you navigate around on the website or just coming into the website. 
Its a problem for all the pages I have made. Anyone who can tell me what to do?

Then i got another question; Why does this table have a width i cant do anything about. Im trying making a table responsiv because i need that, you can see it here: http://thistedbolig.konggulerodhosting.dk/bolig.html

Its at the bottom of the site : " boliger i afdeling " that table all got the same width, only when i got on mobile device i can change it when its small-12, what to do?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Værelser</th>
      <th>Størrelse</th>
      <th>Indskud</th>
      <th>Husleje</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lejlighed</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>38 m2</td>
      <td>8.600</td>
      <td>2.151</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lejlighed</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>50 m2</td>
      <td>11.400</td>
      <td>3.110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lejlighed</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>61 m2</td>
      <td>13.900</td>
      <td>3.758</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lejlighed</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>76 m2</td>
      <td>17.300</td>
      <td>4.421</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The menu code is the same as the thistedbolig site, so i link that code:

```
<nav>
  <div id="topBar" data-toggler="is-active" class=" top-bar row">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="topBar" class="mobile__close hide-for-large"></button>
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="top-bar-left">
        <div class="site-logo">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <p class="mobile__headline hide-for-large">Menu</p>
        <ul class="menu"
            data-responsive-menu="drilldown large-dropdown"
            data-back-button="&lt;li class=&quot;js-drilldown-back drilldown-back&quot;&gt;&lt;a&gt;Back&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Forside</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="search.html">Ledige boliger</a>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><a href="search.html">Ledige boliger 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="search.html">Ledige boliger 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="search.html">Ledige boliger 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="afdelinger.html">Afdelinger</a></li>
          <li><a href="article.html">Info</a>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Info 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Info 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Info 3 </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please provide the code for us to understand.

Comment: Can you describe the jumping around you're getting? If you mean on your first page load then you should hide the dropdown using CSS. Otherwise it seems to be working fine

Comment: @Serge Maybe you got it right. But i was wondering if I chould just show the body when content is loaded, but then the equlizer don't work.